# How to get OPTIONAL interface method implementation in C# like in Objective-C 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, objective-c

Objective-C has protocol which is the equivalence of interface in C#. Nevertheless C# enforces to implement all method like in Objective-C 1.0.

But in Objective-C 2.0, it is now possible to mark some method in protocol as optional. Does C# allow this or will it allow this in some future?

In theory enforcing is the very purpose of interface but in practice I have experienced the burden of this hard rule in complex project: you have to create many many interfaces which can become hard to manage design or refactor. So for me this evolution of Objective-C 1.0 to Objective-C 2.0 does really make sense.

As Microsoft is generally pragmatic it would be great if they could do this also.

Comment: Nitpick: chronologically speaking, C# interfaces are the equivalent to Objective-C protocols, not the other way around. Objective-C was the main influence on the design of Java (in fact, when NeXTStep went belly-up, several members of the Objective-C design team migrated to Sun), and protocols (called interfaces in Java) were one of the many things taken. C#, of course, got them from Java. Objective-C got them from Smalltalk, but in Smalltalk they are only a documentation convention, whereas in Objective-C, Java and C#, they are an actual language feature. And thus ends today's history lesson.

Comment: Then it would not be `Interface` anymore.

Comment: Java may be inspired from Objective C but not on the essential part which is Smalltalk messaging. C# is very close to Java as it was for legal reason that Microsoft couldn't modify Java for Windows Platform.

Comment: it's actually a nice 'logical' design sub-pattern type of concept that was provided by @Anthony Pegram due to asking this:optional vs mandatory interfaces - maybe useful someday, +1

Comment: @Jörg NeXTSTEP never went "belly up".  It turned into OpenStep and then Mac OS X.  Along the way, there were engineers that shifted from company to company.  Naughton being the person that left NeXT to join Gosling at Sun on the Oak -- later Java -- project.

Comment: Well it doesn't matter that he joins Gosling because Java is very far from Objective C. Ask a java guy to program in Objective it's totally different paradigm. Objective C is closer in philosophy to dynamic language like javascript than Java.

Comment: @ivo what do you mean by "nice" :) I find nice but others here don't think so.

Comment: @user310291 all can be useful sometimes in software design things can be very subjective & the wrong things can work better then the right things in certain cases. I think the only good design patter really is: Don't follow design pattern specification blindly. Also everyone is entitled to an opinion & I personally find to classify your interfaces as mandatory or not may come in handy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest you can come is an explicit implementation (so the method is not part of the publicly visible API) and then go a step further and have it throw just in case someone found it and tried to use it.

```
void ICanDoSomething.DoSomething()
{
    throw new NotSupportedException(); // optional
}
```

When someone instantiates an object that implements the interface, they would not see the explicit implementation unless they are referring to the object *as* the interface.

An example from the BCL is an array, which implements `ICollection<T>`. `ICollection<T>` has an `Add` method that is not useful for a fixed-length array. It's an explicit implementation in the case of an array, and if you try to use it, it will throw.

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3 };
ICollection<int> collection = (ICollection<int>)array;
collection.Add(4); // throws NotSupportedException
```

Of course, if you can avoid some "optional" behavior, it's best to do so. Split it out into multiple interfaces, for example, so a class only implements the interface for the behavior that is actually desired.

Comment: Probably the best answer, will have to re-read and think about it then I will mark it as good one :)

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible, because this would be against the nature of an interface. If you could make the implementation of a method optional, what would happen if a piece of code expects this method to work but it doesn't, as it isn't implemented? An interface is there to offer a contract of methods which are implemented and can be used, optional methods would be against that. If you are in need of doing this, you are probably violating the single responseability rule anyway.

Comment: I agree.  The "optional" thing for interfaces in Objective C is a bad idea and completely screws with the entire purpose for them.  If the signature should only be used by some classes, then break it out into their own interface.

Comment: It's a bad idea only in theory. In practice as I said it is not so a bad idea. Like SOAP was a good idea compared to REST it appears that Google chose REST.